# React.JS: Form problem to make post caused from useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a form and I have noticed that when I submit data, they are not writing in the db (with error 400). So I have investigated and I have noticed that one api call that I make in useEffect is done about 5 time during the submit. (I have tried to comment this part and It works!)

I have a first part of form, in which with a select I make a choose, this value is used to make an api call (and there is the problem) to give back some data to use in the form.

```
return (
    <AvForm model={isNew ? {} : userClientAuthorityEntity} onSubmit={saveEntity}>
        <AvInput
            id="client-application"
            data-cy="application"
            type="select"
            className="form-control"
            name="application"
            onChange={handleChangeApp} // there i save the value applicationApp
            required
            value={applicationApp}
        >
            <option value="" key="0">
                Select
            </option>
            {applicationListAPP ? 
                applicationListAPP.map(value => {
                    return (
                        <option value={value.appCod} key={value.appCod}>
                            {value.appDescription}
                        </option>
                    );
                })
                : null}
        </AvInput>
    </AvGroup>
    
    <ShowRoleApp applicationRole={applicationApp} /> // so there I pass the value to make the api call 
)
    
const ShowRoleApp = ({ applicationRole }) => {
  const [profili, setProfili] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  if (!applicationRole) {
    return <div />;
  }
  // I think that it the problem, because it recall GetProfili
  useEffect(() => {
    async function init() {
      await GetProfili(applicationRole)
        .then((res) => {
          console.log('res ', res);
          setProfili(res);
          setIsLoading(true);
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log('err ', err));
    }
    init();
  }, []);

  return isLoading ? (
    RenderProfili(profili, applicationRole)
  ) : (
    <div className='d-flex justify-content-center'>
      <div className='spinner-border text-primary' role='status'>
        <span className='visually-hidden'></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const GetProfili = async (appCod) => {
  const chiamata = 'myApi' + appCod.toString();
  const res = await fetch(chiamata);
  const result = res.clone().json();
  return result;
};

const RenderProfili = (profili, applicationRole) => {
    const ruoliOperatore = profili ? profili.filter(it => it.appCod.toString() === applicationRole.toString()) : null;
        return (
          <AvGroup>
            <Label for="sce-profiloutentepa-pucCod">Profile (*)</Label>
             // other code for the form...
```

So in your opinion how can i do to call the GetProfili without recall every time when I submit the form?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could define `GetProfili` as a custom hook an manage the `useEffect` call in it.
It will return the `isLoading` and `profili` instances.

Try to change your code like this.

GetProfili:

```
const GetProfili = (appCod) => {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
    const [profili, setProfili] = useState([])

    const loadProfili = async () => {
        const chiamata = 'myApi' + appCod.toString();
        const res = await fetch(chiamata);
        
        setProfili(res.json())
        setIsLoading(false)
    } 
    
    useEffect(() => {
        loadProfili()
    }, [])

  return { isLoading, profili };
};
```

ShowRoleApp:

```
const ShowRoleApp = ({ applicationRole }) => {
    
  if (!applicationRole) {
    return <div />;
  }

  const { isLoading, profili } = GetProfili(applicationRole)

  return isLoading ? (
    RenderProfili(profili, applicationRole)
  ) : (
    <div className='d-flex justify-content-center'>
      <div className='spinner-border text-primary' role='status'>
        <span className='visually-hidden'></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I have tried what you suggest, but I receive an error on setProfili(res.json())
`Argument of type 'Promise <any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction <any []>'.
  The type 'Promise <any>' is not assignable to the type '(prevState: any []) => any []'.
    Type 'Promise <any>' does not provide signature matches '(prevState: any []): any []'. `

Comment: Can you post the result of a `console.log(res)` after the fetch call?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really understand the question but I can say something that might help. The useEffect() hook gets called on every rerender of the component so if it updates 5 times its because some states inside the component get updated 5 times. Also states are updated in child components update the parent.